# How to leave the chat channel?

Tags: getstream-io

I'm building a client with stream-chat-react for chat client with stream chat API. I implemented `setUser`, `create a channel`, but I'm struggling with `leaving` a channel.

I'm implementing a chat on React web app. I've tried with 'stopWatching()` method, but it's not working for my case.

```js
const ControlBar = withChatContext(({ client }) => {

  const leaveChannel = async () => {
    try {
      await channel.stopWatching()
      logger('stop watching')
    } catch (error) {
      logger('stop watching error > ', error)
    }
  }

...

}
```

How can I make just getting out of the one channel and disappeared in `<ChannelList />`

Comment: Do you still get updates on that channel after stopWatching is called. I think you might need to hide the channel. We're releasing a new method called hideChannel somewhere next week. This should do exactly what you need.

Comment: @JaapBakker I called stopWatching, but channel's member count remains the same. It seems just making myself offline. I need somewhat to make leave the channel and removed in members of the channel. If you say so, stopWatching + hideChannel doesn't mean leaving a channel and changing the member count.

Comment: Yeah the member_count won't go down if you hideChannel. Removing members can only be done by moderators and admins, or you'll have to do it server side.

Comment: @JappBakker Thank you for your clarification. That's quite odd to me. If it is a chat service, why don't you have a method for channel member to leave a channel by themselves? I hope to have a method `leaveChannel` soon.

Comment: @JaapBakker I've found one workaround using permissions for channel type. I found I can edit permissions for my channel type in Dashboard. And I gave permission for a channel member to update channel member.

`
{
        "action": "Allow",
        "name": "Users can leave channels",
        "resources": [
            "UpdateChannelMembers"
        ],
        "roles": [
            "user"
        ],
        "owner": false,
        "priority": 50
    },
`

I know it's not a good way, but It is an only workaround without setting up server-side API.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround to edit the permission of channel type. You can connect to the Stream dashboard and go to Chat Overview. then, you can edit the channel type, clicking e.g. messaging. You can modify the permissions of it.

```
...,
# Add UpdateChannelMembers permission
{
        "action": "Allow",
        "name": "Users can leave channels",
        "resources": [
            "UpdateChannelMembers"
        ],
        "roles": [
            "user"
        ],
        "owner": false,
        "priority": 50
    },
...
```